# LLDB: Equivalent of process connect in python

Tags: python, scripting, lldb

I am currently executing:

```
process connect <url>
```

from the lldb command line to make a connection. What I would like to do is to include in a python script to automate making this connection.

What is the python api I need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the SB API this is `SBTarget::ConnectRemote`.  It can't be a SBProcess method because you don't have a process before you call this...

Note, you probably don't want to provide your own `SBListener` to `SBTarget::ConnectRemote`. It (and all the other process creation calls that take a `SBListener`) will use the Debugger's listener if you provide an nil listener.

For instance, if you are writing a Python command to do the connect, then you'll want to let the regular Debugger's event handler to deal with process events after you've connected.

On the off chance you want to try handling process events yourself, the example:

http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lldb/trunk/examples/python/process_events.py

will get you started.

Comment: When I use process connect from the lldb command line, I do not need to specify a listener. This api expects a listener to be passed in. What should I pass in?

Comment: The listener is for if you want to control the events for this one process separately from the other processes managed by this debugger.  In general that isn't necessary, and if you pass in an empty listener, then the debugger will get hooked up to handle events for this process.  If you just want to use Python to connect, then go back the the command line, that's the right thing to do, since the command line assumes the debugger is handling events for all processes.

Comment: Note, if you are interested in driving the process further in your Python code, there's an example of that here: http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lldb/trunk/examples/python/process_events.py.

Comment: If you could update your answer with what you wrote in the comments, I will mark this question as answered.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is still something I am missing. How do I get a valid target object? If I manually call 'process connect <url>', I can call my custom command and my def __lldb_init_module (debugger, dict) function is called. I can then ask the debugger for GetSelectedTarget and it will give me a valid target object. There seems to be a chicken and egg problem here...I need a target to make a connection, but I need to make the connection to have a target. How is this issues resolved?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.  You need to have an SBTarget to create a SBProcess using SBTarget::ConnectRemote.  That isn't cyclic.  I thought you were trying to write a Python-based lldb command part of whose job would be to call ConnectRemote on the current target.  The job of the __lldb_init_module part of your python module for this command is to register said command with the lldb Command interpreter for the debugger it gets passed, that's all.  Then by the time the user invokes your command, they will have made a target.  So your command doesn't have to worry about that.

Comment: Note, in more recent lldb's there's a form of the Python backing command function that takes an SBExecutionContext.  That will include the target that is appropriate for this invocation of the command.  Good to use that API if you can, there are some instances where the selected and the one the command is supposed to use are not the same...